# Numpy, the array doesn't have its own data?

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to use `resize` on an array in this way:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=np.uint8)
a.resize(4,2)
print a
```

and the output is Ok!(I meant that there was no error). But when I run this code:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2,3)
a.resize(4,2)
print a
```

it gave rise to an error, saying that, `ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data`

**My question:** why after applying `reshape` the ownership of array is changed? The ownership is granted to whom !? The `reshape` does not create a new memory and it is performing its operation on the same array memory! So why the ownership will change?

I read [np.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) and [ndarray.resize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html#numpy.ndarray.resize) doc but I can not understand the reason. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424211/transfer-ownership-of-numpy-data). I can check `ndarray.flags` always before applying the `resize` method.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Lets start with the following:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> b = a.reshape(2,3)
>>> b[0,0] = 5
>>> a
array([5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=uint8)
```

I can see here that array `b` is not its own array, but simply a view of `a` (just another way to understand the "OWNDATA" flag). To put it simply both `a` and `b` reference the same data in memory, but `b` is viewing `a` with a different shape. Calling the `resize` function like `ndarray.resize` tries to change the array *in place*, as `b` is just a view of `a` this is not permissible as from the `resize` definition:

> The purpose of the reference count check is to make sure you do not use this array as a buffer for another Python object and then reallocate the memory.

---

To circumvent your issue you can call `resize` from numpy (not as an attribute of a ndarray) which will detect this issue and copy the data automatically:

```
>>> np.resize(b,(4,2))
array([[5, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [5, 2]], dtype=uint8)
```

Edit: As CT Zhu correctly mention `np.resize` and `ndarray.resize` add data in two different ways. To reproduce expected behavior as `ndarray.resize` you would have to do the following:

```
>>> c = b.copy()
>>> c.resize(4,2)
>>> c
array([[5, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: `a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=np.uint8)`, these two gives different results: `np.resize(a, (4,2))` `a.resize(4,2);print a`. It is not a circumvent

Comment: @CTZhu Good point they increase the shape in two different ways.

Comment: Another way is to modify the `shape` attribute of the array. (e.g. `a.shape = (2, 3)`) This reshapes it in-place without creating a new view.