# add zeros to missing values of a matrix using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am obtaining several values of two matrices L and R of expected dimensions of 2200x88 for each ith iteration of a for loop using  Numpy (Python).
some of the matrices have fewer elements for example 1200x55, in those cases I have to add zeros to the matrix to reshape it to be of 2200x88 dimension. I have created the following program to solve that problem:

```
        for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        #more code here, l is matrix 1 of the ith iteration, r is matrix 2 of ith iteration 
ls1, ls2=l.shape
rs1, rs2= r.shape
            if ls1 != 2200 | ls2 != 88:
                l.resize((2200, 88), refcheck=False)
            if rs1 != 2200 | rs2 != 88:
                r.resize((2200, 88), refcheck=False)
            var = np.concatenate((l, r), axis=0).reshape(1,387200)
```

The problem is that when a matrix R or L is detected not to be of dimensions 2200 by 88 I obtain the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Has anyone any recommendations on how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that `l[0] != 2200 | l[1] != 88` should be `ls1 != 2200 | ls2 != 88` and the same thing goes for the `r[0]...` line 2 lines below.

Comment: yes, my bad! I copied the wrong code. Thank you for spotting it.

Comment: You need to clean up the indentation, e.g. the `for` line.  Also are you missing some `if` statements?

Comment: what code define l.shape and r.shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `l` is a matrix, `l[0]` is a strip of that matrix, an array.

This part:

```
if l[0] != 2200 | l[1] != 88
```

is causing your error, since you're trying to "or" two arrays.

So instead of

```
ls1, ls2=l.shape
rs1, rs2= r.shape
if l[0] != 2200 | l[1] != 88:
    l.resize((2200, 88), refcheck=False)
if r[0] != 2200 | r[1] != 88:
    r.resize((2200, 88), refcheck=False)
```

Consider:

```
 if l.shape != (2200, 88):
     l.resize((2200, 88), refcheck=False)
 if r.shape != (2200, 88):
     r.resize((2200, 88), refcheck=False)
```

Comment: I have tried and I get: ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data

Comment: Thats a different issue, but consider looking at answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253144/numpy-the-array-doesnt-have-its-own-data)

Comment: I think the answer may be to do the following c = b.copy() but do I have to create a separate concatenate function to do that?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about your code.  If you copy both matrices `ll,rr = l.copy(),r.copy()` then your concatenate line should look like `var = np.concatenate((ll, rr), axis=0).reshape(1,387200)`