# resize array created with linspace: array does not own its data

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am creating an array with **linspace**:

```
>> a = np.linspace(0, 4, 9)
>> a
>> array([0. , 0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3. , 3.5, 4. ])
```

I am resizing it succesfully as below:

```
>> a.resize(3, 3)
>> a
>> array([[0. , 0.5, 1. ],
       [1.5, 2. , 2.5],
       [3. , 3.5, 4. ]])
```

However, when I try to resize it as below:

```
a.resize(4, 2, refcheck=False)
```

This gives me the following error:
**`ValueError: cannot resize this array: it does not own its data`**

When I create the same value array and resize it, array is resized succesfully:

```
>> b = np.array([0. , 0.5, 1. , 1.5, 2. , 2.5, 3. , 3.5, 4. ])
>> b.resize(4, 2, refcheck=False)
>> b
>> array([[0. , 0.5],
       [1. , 1.5],
       [2. , 2.5],
       [3. , 3.5]])
```

Both of `a` and `b` are `numpy.ndarray`

**My question:** Why does `resize()` give this error when the array is created with `linspace`? When resized with 3x3 (and so used all elements of the array), it does not complain about ownership but why does it complain with 4x2 even if I use `refcheck=False` option?

I read the docs about `linspace` and `resize` but cannot find an answer about the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect `a.flags` of an array created by `np.linspace()` you will see that OWNDATA is False.  This means the array is a view of another array.  You can use `a.base` to see that other array.

As for why `np.linspace()` produces arrays with OWNDATA=False, see the source code: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/core/function_base.py#L23-L165

The last part of the code does this:

```
return y.astype(dtype, copy=False)
```

The `copy=False` means the result is a view.  To get an array with OWNDATA=True, you can use `a.copy()`.  Then `resize()` with refcheck=False will work.

See also: [Numpy, the array doesn't have its own data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253144/numpy-the-array-doesnt-have-its-own-data)

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I think this answer is superior to the marked duplicate (though it's good to cite that SO).  The `resize` method operate in-place, while the function returns a new array.  The function result doesn't OWNDATA either, ending with a `reshape`.  Despite the name, the `resize` method and function are worlds apart in execution.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks for your input, I have reopened the question.